# Delete some columns, re-arrange remaining columns and move processed files for multiple .csv files using SSIS 2008 R2

Tags: excel, ssis

Googled for some tips on how to crack this. But did not get any helpful hits. 
Now, I wonder if I can achieve the same in SSIS or not.

**There are multiple .csv files in a folder.** What I am trying to achieve is to:

1. open each .csv file (I would use a parameter as filenames' change)
2. Delete some columns
3. re-arrange the remaining columns in a particular order
4. save the .csv file (without the Excel confirmation message box)
5. Close the .csv file
6. Move the processed file to another folder.

and re-start the entire above process until all the .csv files in the folder are processed.

Initially I thought I can use the For Each Loop Container and Execute process Task to achieve this. However, not able to find any resource as to how to achieve the above desired objective.

Example:
**Header of every Source .csv file:**

**CODE** | **NAME** | **Value 1** | **Value 2** | **Value 3** | **DATE** | **QTY** | **PRICE** | **VALUE_ADD** | **ZONE**

I need to delete columns: NAME | VALUE_ADD | ZONE from each file and re-arrange the columns in the below order.

*Desired column order:*

**CODE** | **DATE**| **Value 1** | **Value 2** | **Value 3** | **PRICE** | **QTY**

I know this is possible within SSIS. But am not able to figure it out. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, managed to get the desired result. In the end, it seemed so simple.

My main motive for creating this package was that I had a lot of .csv files that needed the laborious task of opening each file and running a macro that eliminated a couple of columns, rearranged the remaining columns in the desired format. Then I had to manually save each of the files after clicking on the Excel Confirmation boxes. That was becoming too much. I wanted just a one click approach.

Giving a detailed way of what I did. Hope it helps people who are tying to get data from multiple .csv files as source, then get only the desired columns in the order they need, and finally save the desired output as .csv files into a new destination.

In brief, all I had to use was use:

- a **For Each Loop Container**
- a **Data Flow Task** within it.

And within the Data Flow Task:

- a **Flat File Source**
- a **Flat File Destination**
- 2 **Flat File Connection Managers** - One each for *Source* and *Destination*.

Also, had to use 3 *Variables* - all *String* Data Types with Project Scope - which I named: **CurrFileName**, **DestFilePath**, and **FolderPath**.

.

***Detailed Steps:***

Set default values to the variables:

**CurrFileName:** Just provide the name of one of the .scv files (test.csv) for temporary purpose.

**FolderPath:** Provide the path where your source .csv files are located (**C:\SSIS\Data\Input**)

**DestFilePath:** Provide the Destination path where you want to save the processed files (**C:\SSIS\Data\Input\Output**)

**Step 1**: Drag a For Each Loop Container to the Control Flow area.

**Step 2**: In collection, select the enumerator as 'Foreach File Enumerator'.

**Step 3**: Under Enumerator Configuration, under Folder: provide the folder path where the .csv files are located (In my case, **C:\SSIS\Data\Input**) and in Files:, provide the extension (in our case: *.csv)

**Step 4**: Under Retrieve file name, select 'Name and extension' radio button.

**Step 5**: Then go to the Variable Mappings section and select the Variable (in my case: *User::CurrFileName*.

**Step 6**: Create the source connection (let's call it **SrcConnection**)- right-click in the Connection Managers area and select the Flat File Connection manager and select one of the .csv files (for temporary purpose). Go to the Advanced tab and provide the correct desired data type for the columns you wish to keep. Click OK to exit.

**Step 7**: Then go to the Properties of this newly created source Flat File Connection and click the small box adjacent to the *Expressions* field to open the **Property Expressions Editor**. under 'Property', select 'ConnectionString' and in the Expression space, enter: **@[User::FolderPath] + "\" + @[User::CurrFileName]** and click OK to exit.

**Step 8**: In Windows Explorer, create a new folder inside your Source folder (in our case: **C:\SSIS\Data\Input\Output)**

**Step 9**: Create the Destination connection (let's call it **DestConnection**) - right-click in the Connection Managers area and select the Flat File Connection manager and select one of the .csv files (for temporary purpose). Go to the Advanced tab and provide the correct desired data type for the columns you wish to keep. Click OK to exit.

**Step 10**: Then go to the Properties of this newly created source Flat File Connection and click the small box adjacent to the *Expressions* field to open the **Property Expressions Editor**. under 'Property', select 'ConnectionString' and in the Expression space, enter: **@[User::DestFilePath]  + @[User::CurrFileName]** and click OK to exit.

**Step 11**: Drag the Data Flow Task to the Foreach Loop Container.

**Step 12**: In the Data Flow Task, drag a Flat File Source and in the Flat file connection manager: select the source connection (in this case: **SrcConnection**). In Columns, de-select all the columns and select only the columns that you require (in the order that you require) and click OK to exit.

**Step 13**: Drag a Flat File Destination to the Data Flow Task and in the Flat File Connection manager: select the destination connection (in this case: **DestConnection**). Then, go to the Mappings section and verify if the mappings are as per desired output. Click OK to exit.

**Step 14**: That's it. Execute the package. it should execute without any trouble.

Hope this helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

Easily done using the following four steps :

- Use a "Flat file Connection" to open your CSV.
- Use a "Flat file Source" component to read your CSV.
- Use a "Derived column" component to rearrange your columns.
- Use a "Flat file Destination" component to save your CSV.

Et voilà!

Comment: Thanks Dominic. However, I have many files in the folder and I want it to loop the same things in all the files. I do not think I can use a parameter or variable in a Flat File Connection. Can I? Hence, i was looking for an approach like using a ForEach Container and a Execute Process Task, etc.

Comment: You can use a variable in a connection. The best way to achieve that IMO is to create a package that do all the job (connection manager, source, transform, destination) and then call that package multiple time for another package, each time having a variable defined on the execute package task that will overwrite a variable in the child package.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, But I wanted to achieve this using only 1 package and in a single execution all the files should be processed. Finally got to it :-)

Comment: You can add a foreach file loop instead of master/child package, but this is not common best practices. It works, but you will have problem someday when you forget to delete a file, or some other process copy a file to your directory. Glad I helped a bit!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear why you want to use SSIS to do this: your task seems to be to manipulate text files outside the database, and it's usually much easier to do this in a small script or program written in a language with good CSV parsing support (Perl, Python, PowerShell, whatever). If this should be part of a larger package then you can simply call the script using an Execute Process task. SSIS is a great tool, but I find it quite awkward for a task like this.

Comment: My main motive for creating this package was that I had a lot of .csv files that needed the laborious task of opening each file and running a macro that eliminated a couple of columns, rearranged the remaining columns in the desired format. Then I had to manually save each of the files after clicking on the Excel Confirmation boxes. That was becoming too much. I wanted just a one click approach.